# windows batch dir command get last modified directory starting with string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, substr, dir

I want to get the last modified directory starting with a string `stringEx...` in a windows batch file.

For example: I have a folder containing sub-directories like this :

```
- Directory
  -Subdirectory1
  -Subdirectory2
  -Anothersubdirectory
....
```

I tried with this but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set foundedFolder

FOR /F %%i IN ('dir C:\Directory | subtsr "Anoth*" /b /ad-h /od') DO (SET a=%%i)

%foundedFolder%=%a%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is `subtsr`  an external command ?

Comment: Just `dir C:\Directory\Anoth* /b /ad-h /od`.

Comment: `dir /b  /ad-h /od | find /i "\Anoth"`  ??

Comment: Every folder has a last modified date, but it may or may not be useful, depending on your need. The parent folder modified date will only be updated if a file or folder is created, deleted, or renamed directly within it. It will not change if the contents of a file change, or if a file or folder is created, deleted, or renamed within a child folder. I've never found that useful.

Answer (score 6):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad-h /od "Anoth*"') do set "latestDir=%%~a"
echo(%latestDir%
```