# Get and Sort Last Modified DIR in Batch

Tags: sorting, batch-file, dir

I'm trying to clean up a network folder and to do so I want to get the last modified and who created for the directory.  So far I've found:

```
dir \\server\share /Q
```

and that works great showing the owner but it sorts the file or sub directory alphabetically.  How can I get the last modified and then sort by that?

And is there a way to export each column to a CSV file?  I tried:

```
echo > folder_owners.csv
echo >> folder_owners.csv
dir \\server\share /Q >> folder_owners.csv
```

but that seems to randomly seperate things, and only into 1 or 2 columns.

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132814/windows-batch-dir-command-get-last-modified-directory-starting-with-string) but I don't feel like it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
DIR \\server\share /Q /O-D /TW /AD
```

To separate columns, `FOR` must be used:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4,* SKIP=4" %a IN ('DIR \\server\share /Q /O-D /TW /AD') DO (
    ECHO Date time: %a %b
    ECHO     Owner: %d
    ECHO  Filename: %e
    ECHO.
)
```

Note this will also parse footer...

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I tried writing that to file and it gave nothing.  So it tried just the cmd `dir \\server\share /p /Q /O-M` and it says "Parameter format not correct - "M" and returns nothing.

Comment: Corrected... In batch file, `%` must be replaced with `%%`.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked great grabbing all the folders, but how can I get files included?  Some people don't put files in folders, they just throw them on in the share drive or create shortcuts and leave them everywhere.

Comment: Remove `/AD` option. Check `DIR /?` to get command help (as in other DOS commands).